# What is the confidence interval for model that is supposed to have mean of 'zero'?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I'm trying to analyze some dataset. I have a model. This model predicts some values. There are real values also known. I calculated the differences between the predicted and real outputs. Ideally, the mean should be 'zero', right? But what should be the confidence interval? For example, for usual formula for 95% CI, should it be:
$$
\bar X\pm\frac{1.96SD}{\sqrt n)}?
$$
Or should I just choose an ideal mean of zero? Or an ideal standard deviation of 1? 
Basically, I want to find the values that do not fit into this confidence interval, i.e. values that are too far from ideal mean of 'zero'.

Comment: look up the term 'standardized residuals'. That should lead you to what you want to do.

Comment: You should be much more explicit about your model and how it was estimated, as it may affect the specifics of attempted answers.